# SQLAlchemy with multiple binds - Dynamically choose bind to query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 4 different databases, one for each one of my customers (medical clinics), which all of them have the exact same structure.

In my application, I have models such as `Patient`, `Doctor`, `Appointment`, etc.

Let's take one of them as an example:

```py
class Patient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "patients"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String, index=True)
    last_name = Column(String, index=True)
    date_of_birth = Column(Date, index=True)
```

I've figured out that with the help of binds I can create different databases and associate each model to a different bind. So I have this configuration:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/main'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'clinic1':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/clinic1',
    'clinic2':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/clinic2',
    'clinic3':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/clinic3',
    'clinic4':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/clinic4'
}
```

Now I'm trying to achieve two things:

1. I want that when I create tables using `db.create_all()` it will create the `patients` table in all 4 databases (clinic1->clinic4)
2. I want to be able to choose a specific bind dynamically (in runtime), so that any query such as `Patient.query.filter().count()` will run against the chosen bind database

Ideally, it would behave like this:

```py
with DbContext(bind='client1'):
    patients_count = Patient.query.filter().count()
    print(patients_count)

# outside of the `with` context we are back to the default bind
```

However, doing this:

```py
patients_count = Patient.query.filter().count()
```

without specifying a bind, will raise an error (as the `patients` table does not exist in the default bind)

Any code example that can guide how this can be done would be highly appreciated!

P.S. It might be that you would suggest not to use different databases and instead use one with different columns / tables but please stick to my example and try to explain how this can be done using this pattern of multiple identical databases
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## 1. Create tables in all binds

Observation: `db.create_all()` calls `self.get_tables_for_bind()`.

Solution: Override `SQLAlchemy` `get_tables_for_bind()` to support `'__all__'`.

```py
class MySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):

    def get_tables_for_bind(self, bind=None):
        result = []
        for table in self.Model.metadata.tables.values():
            # if table.info.get('bind_key') == bind:
            if table.info.get('bind_key') == bind or (bind is not None and table.info.get('bind_key') == '__all__'):
                result.append(table)
        return result
```

Usage:

```py
# db = SQLAlchemy(app)  # Replace this
db = MySQLAlchemy(app)  # with this

db.create_all()
```

## 2. Choose a specific bind dynamically

Observation: `SignallingSession` `get_bind()` is responsible for determining the bind.

Solution:

1. Override `SignallingSession` `get_bind()` to get the bind key from some context.
2. Override `SQLAlchemy` `create_session()` to use our custom session class.
3. Support the context to choose a specific bind on `db` for accessibility.
4. Force a context to be specified for tables with `'__all__'` as bind key, by overriding `SQLAlchemy` `get_binds()` to restore the default engine.

```py
class MySignallingSession(SignallingSession):
    def __init__(self, db, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(db, *args, **kwargs)
        self.db = db

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        if mapper is not None:
            info = getattr(mapper.persist_selectable, 'info', {})
            if info.get('bind_key') == '__all__':
                info['bind_key'] = self.db.context_bind_key
                try:
                    return super().get_bind(mapper=mapper, clause=clause)
                finally:
                    info['bind_key'] = '__all__'
        return super().get_bind(mapper=mapper, clause=clause)


class MySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    context_bind_key = None

    @contextmanager
    def context(self, bind=None):
        _context_bind_key = self.context_bind_key
        try:
            self.context_bind_key = bind
            yield
        finally:
            self.context_bind_key = _context_bind_key

    def create_session(self, options):
        return orm.sessionmaker(class_=MySignallingSession, db=self, **options)

    def get_binds(self, app=None):
        binds = super().get_binds(app=app)
        # Restore default engine for table.info.get('bind_key') == '__all__'
        app = self.get_app(app)
        engine = self.get_engine(app, None)
        tables = self.get_tables_for_bind('__all__')
        binds.update(dict((table, engine) for table in tables))
        return binds

    def get_tables_for_bind(self, bind=None):
        result = []
        for table in self.Model.metadata.tables.values():
            if table.info.get('bind_key') == bind or (bind is not None and table.info.get('bind_key') == '__all__'):
                result.append(table)
        return result
```

Usage:

```
class Patient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "patients"
    __bind_key__ = "__all__"  # Add this
```

Test case:

```
with db.context(bind='clinic1'):
    db.session.add(Patient())
    db.session.flush()         # Flush in 'clinic1'
    with db.context(bind='clinic2'):
        patients_count = Patient.query.filter().count()
        print(patients_count)  # 0 in 'clinic2'
    patients_count = Patient.query.filter().count()
    print(patients_count)      # 1 in 'clinic1'
```

---

## About foreign keys referencing the default bind

You have to specify the `schema`.

Limitations:

- MySQL:

  - Binds must be in the same MySQL instance. Otherwise, it has to be a plain column.
  - The foreign object in the default bind must already be committed.
    Otherwise, when inserting an object that references it, you will get this lock error:

    > MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
- SQLite: Foreign keys across databases are not enforced.

Usage:

```py
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/main'


class PatientType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "patient_types"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "main"}  # Add this, based on database name

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...


class Patient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "patients"
    __bind_key__ = "__all__"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    # patient_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("patient_types.id"))     # Replace this
    patient_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("main.patient_types.id"))  # with this
    patient_type = relationship("PatientType")
```

Test case:

```py
patient_type = PatientType.query.first()
if not patient_type:
    patient_type = PatientType()
    db.session.add(patient_type)
    db.session.commit()        # Commit to reference from other binds

with db.context(bind='clinic1'):
    db.session.add(Patient(patient_type=patient_type))
    db.session.flush()         # Flush in 'clinic1'
    with db.context(bind='clinic2'):
        patients_count = Patient.query.filter().count()
        print(patients_count)  # 0 in 'clinic2'
    patients_count = Patient.query.filter().count()
    print(patients_count)      # 1 in 'clinic1'
```

Comment: aaron, This is a very informative answer which also teaches a lot about good programming practices. I have tried your code example which worked. Now when I've tried to add another model (let's say PatientType) which should be part the default bind (let's call it "general" bind), and to connect it with a ForeignKey to Patient (patient_type_id = Column(ForeignKey("patient_types.id"))) I'm getting "Cannot add foreign key constraint". Can you please add to your answer a quick example of how to reference this Patient model from binds (clinic1->4) to a model in "general" bind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @yanivps I have added a section on that.

Comment: Your added section is very clear and the way you write answers is easy to grasp. I am grateful for your time and efforts. It is very strange that I couldn't find a solution to this problem that in my opinion isn't that far fetched, while sqlalchemy has been here for quite long time.

Comment: Update: this does work, however I needed to close my session when switching between databases. Thanks for the write up aaron

Comment: @aaron you may find more details in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76744251/flask-sql-alchemy-with-multiple-dynamic-binds), I managed to reproduce the error but it is still not fully solved.

Comment: @notify_my_threads I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76756563/8601760) with a thread-safe implementation of `context_bind_key`.