# How to select bind in ModelView based on user selection in Flask session

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

Is there a way to select the db bind based on user selection? In my case, I want to change the db bind based on user selected country. If US, connect to db_us, and if UK, select db_uk.

However, as soon as the application loads, I call db.init_app() which already selects db_us and the models are set, the blueprints are configured and then the login form with country selection is loaded. The user selects UK and enters username and password, but despite having the country selected in session I am not able to reset the models with the new bind_key.

Here is some code:

```
# app.py
def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):
    db.init_app(app)
    admin.add_view(UsersAdmin(db.session))
    admin.init_app(app)
    ...


# /partners/model.py
class Partners(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'partners'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)


# /user/model.py
class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String(STRING_LEN), unique=True)
    partner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("PARTNERS.id"))
    partners = db.relationship("Partners", uselist=True, backref="user")


# Customized User model admin
class UsersAdmin(ModelView):
    # set the form fields to use
    form_columns = ('name', 'email', 'partners')
    column_list = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'stores')
    
    # Override query methods to add database switchers
    def _run_view(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        selectedCountry = session['selectedcountry']
        with db.context(bind=selectedCountry):
            return super()._run_view(fn, *args, **kwargs)
```

It still queries against US db.

---

[SQLAlchemy with multiple binds - Dynamically choose bind to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69561572/sqlalchemy-with-multiple-binds-dynamically-choose-bind-to-query) helped me, but I still have an issue with using db bind with a flask-admin ModelView. I am now able to use the correct db to login but in Flask Admin page User Create form, the form field Partners drop down list always loads US relevant options. How can I set bind in ModelView?

```py
# /frontend/views.py
def login():
    ...
    user, authenticated = Users.authenticate(form.login.data, form.password.data, country=form.country.data)
    if user and authenticated:
        ...
        session['selectedcountry'] = form.country.data
        ...


# /user/model.py
@classmethod
def authenticate(cls, login, password, country):
    with db.context(bind=country):
        user = cls.query.filter(Users.email.ilike(login), Users.country.ilike(country)).first()
        ...
```

After applying the suggestion from Aaron regarding overriding UserAdmin._run_view(), I still find view does not query against the db in context. The select list for partners is still loaded from the default db.
Additional issues that I saw was that, even though authentication works fine for each db, the logged in user and email displayed post login is from the other db. For example, I logged in with UK Admin User of db_uk but the name and email is from db_us. See images below. The first image is from the application and second one is from db_uk and db_us respectively. The number of users listed is correct.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to an extend. I am also using flask-admin and I have to load all the view models before the application starts. admin.add_view(UsersAdmin(db.session)) is called in my create_app() function. How can I bypass the db to connect the user selected option from context.

Comment: Override `UsersAdmin._run_view` to specify the context: `with db.context(bind=selectedCountry):`

Comment: @aaron, thank you for your edits and suggestion. I applied it but still the list is not populated from the db in context. Other than authentication, every other function is unreliable. For example, lets say I logged in with db_uk, authentication is correct, but the name of logged in user displayed in that of db_us. Also, in the dashboard screen, the number of users is correct as per db_uk but the name and email of admin user is that of db_us. I have committed my code in github and also edited the above question.

Comment: Specify the context in `def load_user(id):` too. Actually, you can do it in `lms_signallingSession.execute()` for it to work globally — then you can remove `with db.context(bind=selectedCountry):` everywhere except `Users.authenticate()`. Otherwise you need to specify the context explicitly in all places that are relevant for it to not be "unreliable".

Comment: @aaron, thank you for your response. Actually setting the bind in context globally is what I am looking for. Since I will not be changing countries and thereby db in between a user's established session. Can you point me to how I can call lms_signallingSession.execute(). I am not able to get the right parameters to pass.

Comment: Override it, not directly call it. It's called when you access the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the context in `lms_signallingSession.execute()` for it to work globally, and then you can remove `with db.context(bind=selectedCountry):` everywhere except `Users.authenticate()`.

```py
class lms_signallingSession(SignallingSession):
    ...

    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from flask import session
        selectedCountry = session['selectedcountry']
        with self.db.context(bind=selectedCountry):
            return super().execute(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's called whenever you access the DB.

Otherwise, you need to specify the context explicitly in all places that are relevant for it to not be "unreliable". In particular, you are missing it in:

1. `UsersAdmin._run_view()`
2. `def load_user(id):`